# Strange output with ddply when using different variable classes

Tags: r, class, plyr

I'm getting some strange output when using ddply to apply a function to two different variables. It's actually completing the task correctly, but then assumes the format of the output based on which ever variable is named first in my `c(var1, var2)`

All I'm trying to achieve is group my dataframe by `Conversion.ID` and find the max date and if a click happened, which I thought would be simple.

```
> class(wrk.ds$intr.date.time)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
> class(wrk.ds$type.bin)
[1] "numeric"

> wrk.ds.1 <- ddply(wrk.ds, .(Conversion.ID), function(wrk.ds){
+                 click.check = as.numeric(max(wrk.ds$type.bin))
+                 max.intr.date.time = max(wrk.ds$intr.date.time)
+                 c(click.check, max.intr.date.time )})
> head(wrk.ds.1)
  Conversion.ID V1         V2
1  8.930874e+15  1 1406473200
2  4.266128e+16  0 1407955140
3  1.241770e+17  0 1409494260
4  1.309763e+17  1 1407238560
5  1.367159e+17  1 1408196760
6  1.417151e+17  0 1409251260
> 
> #Reversing the c() order
> wrk.ds.1 <- ddply(wrk.ds, .(Conversion.ID), function(wrk.ds){
+                 click.check = as.numeric(max(wrk.ds$type.bin))
+                 max.intr.date.time = max(wrk.ds$intr.date.time)
+                 c(max.intr.date.time, click.check)})
> head(wrk.ds.1)
  Conversion.ID                  V1                  V2
1  8.930874e+15 2014-07-27 16:00:00 1970-01-01 01:00:01
2  4.266128e+16 2014-08-13 19:39:00 1970-01-01 01:00:00
3  1.241770e+17 2014-08-31 15:11:00 1970-01-01 01:00:00
4  1.309763e+17 2014-08-05 12:36:00 1970-01-01 01:00:01
5  1.367159e+17 2014-08-16 14:46:00 1970-01-01 01:00:01
6  1.417151e+17 2014-08-28 19:41:00 1970-01-01 01:00:00
```

My work-around has been to do these in two steps, but I'm really more curious to know if this can be fixed.

I've tried the following, but to no avail.

```
wrk.ds.1 <- ddply(wrk.ds, .(Conversion.ID), function(wrk.ds){
                click.check = as.numeric(max(wrk.ds$type.bin))
                max.intr.date.time = max(wrk.ds$intr.date.time)
                c(click.check, as.POSIXct(max.intr.date.time ))})
```

As a bonus question, can anyone tell me way my labels for my newly created variables aren't getting assigned that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anonymous function you pass to `ddply` should return a data.frame, yours is returning a vector. Change it like this:

```
wrk.ds.1 <- ddply(wrk.ds, .(Conversion.ID), function(DF){
                 click.check = max(DF$type.bin)
                 max.intr.date.time = max(DF$intr.date.time)
                 data.frame(click.check, max.intr.date.time )})
```

Of course, you should use `summarise` instead:

```
wrk.ds.1 <- ddply(wrk.ds, .(Conversion.ID), summarise,
                   click.check = max(type.bin),
                   max.intr.date.time = max(intr.date.time))
```